# How to take a number of NUMERIC user input and WITHOUT KNOWING the range

Tags: c

I want to take a number of input in NUMERIC FORMAT separated by a space and put that into array...When I press enter there should be a termination and previovsly stored values should be there in the array....

Input format: 1 2 3 4 5{Press Enter}           output format: 12345

> In the above output format...
>
> arr[0]=1 ,arr[1]=2 ,arr[2]=3 ,arr[3]=4 ,arr[4]=5

Input format: 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1{Press Enter}   output format: 987654321

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {

        int num[100],a,i,j;
        i=0;

        while(scanf("%d",&a))
        {
            num[i]=a;
            i++;
        }

        for(j=0;j<i;j++)
        {
            printf("%d",num[j]);
        }

    return 0;
    }
```

The above code needs an Non-numeric value to terminate.......And Works fine...!!!

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        int i=1;
        char ch,arr[20];

        scanf("%c",&ch);
        arr[0]=ch;

        while (ch != '\n')
        {
            scanf("%c",&ch);
            arr[i]=ch;
            arr[i+1]='\0';
            i++;
        }
        printf("%s",arr);

    return 0;
    }
```

The above one works only for character input.....And Works fine...!!!

And I want there should be termination on pressing ENTER...FOR NUMERIC Input

Comment: what is the problem? it is unclear

Comment: suggest reading the man page for scanf() as the handling, in the posted code, of the returned value is not correct.

Comment: What's supposed to happen when "1 42 5" is entered?

Comment: please consistently indent the code for readability by us humans.   Suggest indent after every opening brace '{' and un-indent before every closing brace '}'.   4 space indents is sufficient to be visible with proportionally spaced fonts without eating up the available horizontal space.   Never use tabs for indenting as each word processor/editor has the tab width/tab stops set differently

Comment: when 1 42 5 is entered and 'ENTER' botton i.e;'\n' is pressed there should be termination of while loop and should be stored in the array....

Comment: I meant to ask specifically what happens to the number `42`.

Comment: in general, there should be a prompt output to let the user know what they are expected to enter.   The posted code allows the user to enter more than 100 numbers.   The numbers will then be entered past the end of the input buffer.  This is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.  Suggest inserting a check in the code to stop inputing numbers if the input buffer is full

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers, like 100 and 20.  Such magic numbers will make the code a real bear to maintain.  Suggest #define'ing the numbers with meaningful names, using the meaningful names throughout the code.   Note: to avoid possible 'text replacement errors' always surround the numeric values with parens: I.E. '#define MAX_NUMBERS (100)'

Comment: answer should be 1425 {arr[0]=1,arr[1]=42,arr[2]=5} Mr. Weather Vane

Comment: ... and also, what will happen when user enters " 1 ab 3"? In your decimal input example the "ab" does not convert, so willl stop there, but it confounds your char input example.

Comment: IS SHOUTING REALLY NECESSARY??!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a char variable only

**Here below is the code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int arr[100];

int main()
{
    char ch;
    int num;
    int i = 0, c;
    while (scanf("%d%c", &arr[i++], &ch))
        if (ch == '\n') break;

    for (c = 0; c < i; c++)
        printf("%d ", arr[c]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't remove the spaces, apart from that it is good as the `%c` takes (one) space or the `newline`.

Comment: And there is no `c` declared in your code. Note- while taking input please take care of accessing index out of bounds.

Comment: It removed the spaces and also I got my appopreate answer Mr.Weather Vane...see there is a space in printf() statement....

Comment: This code just demonstrate how to take input integer, terminated by newline character without consideration of any kinds of exception.

Comment: now variable    c   has been removed from for loop and declared in starts of main function

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. It accepts digits or spaces, tabs, but stops on `newline` or alpha character.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char ch;
    unsigned num = 0;
    while (1 == scanf("%c", &ch)) {
        if (ch == '\n' || isalpha(ch))
            break;
        if (isdigit(ch))
            num = num * 10 + ch - '0';
    }

    printf ("Number is %u\n", num);
    return 0;
}
```